# Check for Terminal Server in WiX

Tags: installation, wix, terminal-services

Recently I had to "pre-select" an feature inside an WiX product. If the target machine is an Terminal-Server, the Feature should be selected for install.

To check, if the machine realy is used as Terminal-Server or not isn't required, since the installing user can still deselect the feature later.

One way to check for Terminal-Server (and not just an machine with RDP enabled) is to use [GetVersionEx-API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) to check the [wSuiteMask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833(v=vs.85).aspx).

How to check that in WiX?

Answer (score 0):

First we had to link WixUtilExtension.dll (Project-References->Add Reference) [image: Adding WixUtilExtension.dll]

Then use INSTALLLEVEL (as per [mrnx's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7555548/5243037)) to switch between different Features. We default it to "2" (All below 2 will be selected in feature-selection-screen, all above 2 will be de-selected):

```
<!--Default Features: All with levl 1-->
<Property Id="INSTALLLEVEL" Value="2" />
```

Use feature-selection-UI-template (Maybe you have to reference WixUiExtension.dll)

```
<UI>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />
</UI>
```

Now reference the properties, which we want to know:

```
<!--Terminal-Server?-->
<PropertyRef Id="WIX_SUITE_TERMINAL" />
<!--On Terminal-Server this property will be null, if multiple RDP-sessions are allowed-->
<PropertyRef Id="WIX_SUITE_SINGLEUSERTS" />
```

And finally in our Feature-list we have to use the properties inside a condition. The Feature should be de-selected per default, so we set it to one Level higher than the default "2" --> "3".

```
<Feature Id="TerminalServerServiceFeature" Level="3"
          Title="(Feature-Title, i.E.)Terminal-Server-Service"
          AllowAdvertise='no'
          InstallDefault='local'
          Absent='allow'
          Description="Some description for the user, when he clicks on the feature" Display="expand"
          ConfigurableDirectory='APPLICATIONFOLDER'
          >
  <!--Reference to the component (or componentgroup) we want to install-->
  <ComponentRef Id="TerminalServerServiceComponent" />

  <!--This sets this feature to installlevel 1, if the condition evals to true-->
  <Condition Level="1">(WIX_SUITE_TERMINAL="1") AND NOT (WIX_SUITE_SINGLEUSERTS)</Condition>
</Feature>
```

### Testing:

To check, why the condition fails, you have to check the installer log (***msiexec /i YourMsi.msi /l*v "log.log"***).
Something along the lines

> MSI (c) (8C!98) [11:18:27:663]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding
>   WIX_SUITE_SINGLEUSERTS property. Its value is '1'.

for a machine with RDP but **without** multi-rdp-session-support and

> MSI (c) (4C!E0) [11:26:15:422]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding
>   WIX_SUITE_TERMINAL property. Its value is '1'.

for a machine with RDP and multi-rdp-session-support.